# Prior art for ice cream maker insulated with inflatable cushion

Tags: prior-art-request, us20120207901, consumer-food

US Patent Application US20120207901: [INFLATABLE CUSHION](http://www.google.com/patents/us20120207901)

Claim #1 describes an ice cream maker assembly comprising of an inflatable cushion to insulate a an ice cream maker apparatus inside. The rest of the claims generally describe the shape and construction of the air-filled insulator.

This type of air-filled cushion is used commonly as a portable "cooler" for applications from keeping ice from melting to keeping drinks cold. See: Amazon: [Inflatable Cooler](http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=inflatable+cooler).

Substituting more conventional insulators with the air-filled cushion may be unique in this application, but anyone reasonable knowledgeable about insulating methods would already be familiar with this option. Would simply substituting one material for another well-known material in this application be considered prior art?

Can someone find an inflatable cooler that uses these pentagonal sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This application got a non-final rejection at the end of Nov. based  on [Mobley 5666261](http://www.google.com/patents/US5622261) and [Angus 5857351](http://www.google.com/patents/US5857351). If you are interested in it you can look in USPTO public PAIR. There are several things already listed on the record by the applicant and by the examiner.